# Ruby wxRuby GUI XRC to rb error

Tags: ruby, wxwidgets, wxruby, xrc

```
Cannot create wrapper for class without 'subclass'
      attribute
```

It outputs as blank file.
My command is

```
xrcise -o Button.rb Button.xrc
```

I use `DialogBlock` designer.

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard to say, but [this](http://thr3ads.net/wxruby-users/2008/11/387864-xrcise-question#m387867) sounds like the answer to at least a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to set a "subclass name" field related to the form somewhere in DialogBlog project. Without that subclass name **xrcise** can't convert your .xrc to .rb file. 
Another problem that you should be aware of is that current version of **xrcise** which is part of wx_sugar-0.1.22 (this is last version for now) can't work with ruby version 1.9.3 or higher becouse some sintax error with method .each that was changed in this vershion.
To solve this problem the best way is add this:

```
class String 
alias :each :each_line
end
```

right after *require* statements inside the file **xrcise**.
Hope it would be helpfull.

P.S. Sorry for my pure english, currently working on it.